# How to update table with proper ISO Country?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table `MyTable` with data like this:

```
[Production],[Region Country],[CustID]
computer,US,123
phone,CA,321
shirt,NZ,111
```

What I want to do is change the 2 letter country code (ISO) into its full country name for all the records in that table (3 million records).

I have a table `Countries` that has all the 2 letter Country Codes and their "full name".. so I can look up on this table to update.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Countries](
[NumericalCode] [char](3) NOT NULL,
[CountryNameLowerCase] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[CountryNameUpperCase] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[ISO_ALPHA3] [char](3) NOT NULL,
[ISO_ALPHA2] [char](2) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

For `US` it would have this data:

```
840,United States of America,UNITED STATES,USA,US
```

The end result would be a process that looks at the MyTable records, and updates `Region Country` based on its full name in the `Countries` table (the column `CountryNameLowerCase`).

What is the best way to do this (performance wise)?

Comment: Sorry about that.. the full name is "CountryNameLowerCase".

Comment: The table that contains all the ISO Country data is called "Countries".

Answer (score 3):

The simple way is a single, brute-force update using an `UPDATE` with a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE m
  SET [Region Country] = c.CountryNameLowerCase 
  FROM dbo.MyTable AS m
  INNER JOIN dbo.Countries AS c
  ON m.[Region Country] = c.ISO_ALPHA2;
```

Now, it's possible that such an update will generate a tremendous amount of log, as well as page splits as you squeeze more information into every single row (and also think of overhead if you are using data compression). In some cases it may be better to perform the update in batches, e.g. one way would be to cursor for each country combination (and this will work best if your countries are relatively evenly distributed, but won't help much if 90% of the data is `US`):

```
DECLARE @old NVARCHAR(255), @new NVARCHAR(255); -- use the right type here

DECLARE c CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
  FOR SELECT m.[Region Country], c.CountryNameLowerCase
    FROM dbo.MyTable AS m
    INNER JOIN dbo.Countries AS c
    ON m.[Region Country] = c.ISO_ALPHA2
    GROUP BY m.[Region Country], c.CountryNameLowerCase;

OPEN c;

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @old, @new;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;

  UPDATE dbo.MyTable
    SET [Region Country] = @new
    WHERE [Region Country] = @old;

  COMMIT TRANSACTION;

  -- experiment with CHECKPOINT if simple
  -- or BACKUP LOG if full. This will depend
  -- on your current log size and autogrow
  -- settings; it can make things worse.

  --CHECKPOINT;
  --BACKUP LOG yourdb TO DISK ...;
END
```

Another way would be limit rowcount, e.g. replace the relevant portion of the code to something like this, where you limit updates to, say, 1000 rows at a time:

```
DECLARE @rc INT;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

  SET @rc = 1;

  WHILE @rc <> 0
  BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    UPDATE TOP (1000) dbo.MyTable
      SET [Region Country] = @new
      WHERE [Region Country] = @old;

    SET @rc = @@ROWCOUNT;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
  END
```

The key is to keep individual transactions short. Updating all 3 million rows might be tolerable (depending on when you perform this work - e.g. off-hours, maintenance window, etc), but there are several tricks to batch these updates into chunks and minimize the impact on transaction log and concurrency. In some cases this chunking will make the update take longer, but not all, and usually speed is not the primary concern (as you'll discover the first time you lock up a system updating the whole table).

(Working on a blog post about this sort of thing right now, incidentally.)

Comment: Interesting. I often have to perform huge updates like this, but I usually have a primary key to work with, ie. `Key < @Count AND key >= @Count`. However, I like your `@@ROWCOUNT` approach better and will try to use it in the future. Could you include performance metrics on my approach as well? Really looking forward to the blog post.

Comment: @JLo I don't really like the key range approach - since such keys are typically based on IDENTITY columns are natural keys, it is very tough to determine how many actual rows exist between 1-1000, 1001-2000, etc. Also, it would be impossible for me to comment on performance metrics for your schema, data, hardware, etc. That is something you're just going to have to test.